# ADB continuously disconnect devices not show it on Mac OSX

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, adb

I have a problem, The ADB server continuously disconnects the android devices. When I plug the device, for example a Samsung J3 the ADB server detect it and work but after random time the device dissappears.
If I do a adb devices command it shows empty. I have to unplug and plug several times for the adb servers detects it.
If I check off the developer debug options and turn it on again sometimes works and sometimes no in spite of on device system bar shows that it on developer mode.

I have already tried to:

```
-Change the usb cable
-Kill the ADB server an start again
-Update the SDK components
-Turn off the debug mode and on again
```

We have some coworkers and they have the same problem.

What would be the problem?

My config:

```
Mac OS Mojave 10.14.5
Android Studio 3.2.1
Terminals with Android 6,7,8
```

[image]

Comment: Had the same issue, In my case it was the faulty data cable

Comment: I already tried to change the cable to a new Amazon Basics cable and the problem persist

Comment: I have the same problem